# subplot x axis show date replace numbers

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm pretty new to the matplotlib.

I'm trying to draw subplots of cryptos price.

**However, the x axis keeps showing me number instead of Date.**

This really driving me crazy for this afternoon.

Is there anyone knows how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7))
plt.subplots_adjust(top=1.25, bottom=1.2)
for i, month in enumerate(list_df_month, 1):
    plt.subplot(2, 2, i)
    month['Close'].plot()
    plt.ylabel('Close')
    plt.xlabel(None)
    plt.title(f"Price for {coin_name[i - 1]}")
    
plt.tight_layout()
```

The list_df_month is a list of crypto dataframe. Like this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KUrs.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please produce a [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to produce the issue. Regarding your question, the sample data (`df`) is missing to reproduce your scenario.

Comment: Have you tried looking into the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html)?

Comment: I really don't know how to give dataframes. Should I delete my question